# My pure js horizontal scroll wont activate scroll-snap

Tags: javascript, html, css

Updated for Clarity:

I have a javascript function that converts a normal mousewheel scroll to a horizontal scroll. This by itself seems to work. I want this function to activate css snap-scrolling. When I add CSS, the function does not work. To be clear, `shift + scroll` does work. I need normal scrolling to work.

I am using the following code.

```js
//a function to convert normal mousewheel scroll to horizontal scroll

(function() {
  function scrollHorizontally(e) {
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    document.getElementById('flexall-container').scrollLeft -= (delta * 40); // Multiplied by 40
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})();
```

```css
/* some body style */

body {
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

/*style the parent div*/

#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  pointer-events: all;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

/* a class to create each page */

.flexall-container-child {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  /* parent properties */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: baseline;
  /* child properties */
  height: 100vh;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!--parent div-->

<div id="flex-container">
  
  <!-- page 1-->
  
  <section id="page01-container" class="flexall-container-child">
    
    <!-- some arbitrary content-->
    
    <h1 id="title-text">
      Title
    </h1>
    <h3 id="title-subheader">
      Subtitle
    </h3>
    
  </section>
  
  <!-- page 2-->
  
  <section id="page02-container" class="flexall-container-child">
    
    <!--some more arbitrary content-->
    
    <h1 id="title-text-2">Page 2 Title</h1>
  
  </section>
  
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code had (at least) one typo: you named the class with a dot prefix in your HTML:

> `class=".flexall-container-child"`.

I removed the parts that were irrelevant to the core of the question and it works perfectly:

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.flexall-container-child {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <section id="page01-container" class="flexall-container-child">
    <h1 class="page-title">Page 1 Title</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="page02-container" class="flexall-container-child">
    <h1 class="page-title">Page 2 Title</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: The "shift scroll" works perfectly, but it doesn't fix the original issue I had of the pure js scroll seemingly not working. Atleast it doesn't seem to be working for me. I apologize if my question wasn't clear enough, editing it now.